# Theorem styles not working in Frontiers journal template

Tags: overleaf, theorems, journal-publishing, proof-package, mathematics

I am trying this template:
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-frontiers-journal/myxxkvjwqhrv

Which package should be added so that Theorem will start in bold and the qed symbol will appear at the end of the proof?
Thank you.

Comment: If you have been asked to use a specific template you don't change the design of the template. If you do not like the design, use a different class/template. The class loads `amsthm` which under normal circumstances gives theorems with a bold header and can provide a marker in proofs. This class has configured it to do otherwise.